# YII 1.1 - Query Builder: How to fetch multiple IN operator record in the FETCH_KEY_PAIR format

Tags: mysql, yii

We are facing some problem for fetch record in PDO format. See below my example code:

```
$getCategories= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('id,category_name')
        ->from('content_categories')
        ->where('id IN (:id)', array(':id'=>$getContentList['content_category_value']))
        //->where("id IN ({$getContentList['content_category_value']})")
        ->queryAll();
print_r($getCategories); exit;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1525
            [category_name] => TV 
        )

)
```

Above query `$getContentList['content_category_value'])` returns `1525,45` but we are getting only single record.

When we manually execute query:

```
SELECT * FROM `content_categories` WHERE `id` IN (1525,45);
```

It returns:

[image]

Actually we have two category but above query fetch only one. Could you please check and help me to how we show multiple record fetch by using PDO concept.

Answer (score 1):

If `$getContentList['content_category_value']` is a string, then it will be used in query as a string. So you're probably getting something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `content_categories` WHERE `id` IN ('1525,45');
```

If you want to build `IN` condition, you need to use array of values with `IN` operator:

```
->where(['in', 'id', explode(',' $getContentList['content_category_value'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can make a try like this,

```
 $getCategories= Yii::app()->db-
 >createCommand()
    ->select('id,category_name')
    ->from('content_categories')
    ->where(array('in', 'id', 
    $getContentList['content_category_value']))    
    ->queryAll();
print_r($getCategories); exit;
```

Comment: It returns the one record.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this one. Here is the solution.

Code:

```
$getCategories= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id,category_name')
    ->from('content_categories')
    ->where(array('in', 'id', array($getContentList['content_category_value'])))
    ->queryAll();
print_r($getCategories); exit;
```